# Delay when I'm resign the keyboard after scrolling the tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uisearchbar

I implemented

```
scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];}
```

to dismiss the keyboard when I begin scrolling the tableview on the search page. But there is a kink and a delay before the table can smoothly scroll. Help?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting this on your tableView:

```
   self.tableView.delaysContentTouches = NO;

   [self.tableView.view endEditing:YES];
```

instead of

```
   [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

That property defaults to YES. It delays touches to the content of the table view cells by a fraction of a second, to help it recognise the difference between a tap and a drag.

Comment: i will give you a up vote but it turns out you could do two things, one is to disable animation to the view upon a keyboard dismissal notification. or actually it's a simulator issue as I tried the code on the device and it worked without a kink.

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                 selector:@selector(willHideKeyboard:) 
                                     name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification 
                                   object:nil];

- (void)willHideKeyboard:(NSNotification *)notification {
       [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
  }

Answer (score 1):

UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey is a constant string identifier the animation duration, so there is where of enabling and disabling the animation.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                 selector:@selector(willHideKeyboard:) 
                                     name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification 
                                   object:nil];

- (void)willHideKeyboard:(NSNotification *)notification {
       [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
  }
```

hope this might help you.